# How to load/build Chrome App/Extension and run programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to make a Chrome App similar to Google's own Chrome Dev Editor, an application built using web standards to create Chrome Apps/Extensions

In Chrome Dev Editor, it's possible to run the Chrome apps/extensions you create right within the app itself. It builds the apps and executes them.

Is there a specific API to do this for the app I want to make? If so what is it and where is the documentation for it?

Any guidance on this subject would be appreciated.

Thank you!
-Rick

Comment: It is whitelisted for [chrome.developerPrivate](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/developerPrivate)

Comment: Well, this makes me want to cry. lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome Dev Editor is whitelisted for the [chrome.developerPrivate](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/developerPrivate) api. You cannot deploy an app with this capability to the webstore.

Fortunately, you can use this api by loading as an unpacked extension, adding the `"developerPrivate"` and `"management"` permissions, and setting the [key manifest property](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key) to one of those whitelisted keys.

If your users are Chrome app/extension developers, they will be familiar with loading unpacked extensions, so you could ask them to do it themselves to access these features and distribute a version without those features to the webstore.

You can include an option to export the source and automatically insert a manifest key using chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(), and checking if chrome.developerPrivate is defined before using it in your code.

whitelisted keys:

- [Chrome Dev Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pnoffddplpippgcfjdhbmhkofpnaalpg): "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA2OvldPjAqgEboHyyZM7GpCMmGMSQ8aExOlQyOhN3C9fDRXqnAN/Ie20TEwD9Eb2CciV3Ru4Gm7PmDnkHzsljD84qLgBdN39FzPGDyViXTS442xTElWRZMZQfJYQpbMpiePL720kTHgLLAcwTgdP9DnvRPrKukIs/U4Y76NFk7NNbsNOc6FWisLJykw2POTB1RR5ZlZrA4Ax1P7kt7qQdomE6i8wy1TA1jDhG8AhEXKRfpyELvJmzyVIyR9uiSHDHCdihiS5oyjADjmmbklvL7Ns0cSAgEX/lWN8UX8r17zoKZzJ0MkmCQ5Nlfql8qUtn2oZXaHztkkAcXCxkq9/37QIDAQAB"
- [Spark (dev)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hpenkfongmodpaiknffeeeohcoilclii): "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAiC2CjQDYZcE1Pn8QHpLh1F32QiJqcO63CObY4ulPEHHmIDfIyflB2WXc7D1bDJtHBahkJEtHY4I8wN8gjowgYVKiiqMpwiuV7Evivyf7Qyvg537Kb0aBdGKVFCpk12H/Z9k835BTWZ3t/uk/ZK2r4fwUF06LYWtZ3XS1W5OrV0NTxGF/keX4qidKMDl3pKLNjKPSPl0G3WFEMui+L68VnC2HzCfrpyrC1/oGGLTa2xg/lkEZhzuUUjWsar8YazZYmVPmZQOjdyls/tGxrVac3IcDaSve40PuKgmmn7H2Gb1h4NKRbDTgBhqmIewQCGpuHMRf/EXNDROhNCx2byStkwIDAQAB"
- [Spark (nightly)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kcjgcakhgelcejampmijgkjkadfcncjl): "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwqXKrcvbi1a1IjFM5COs07Ee9xvPyOSh9dhEF6kwBGjAH6/4F7MHOfPk+W04PURi707E8SsS2iCkvrMiJPh4GnrZ3fWqFUzlsAcUljcYbkyorKxglwdZEXWbFgcKVR/uzuzXD8mOcuXRLu0YyVSdEGzhfZ1HkeMQCKEncUCL5ziE4ZkZJ7I8YVhVG+uiROeMg3zjxxSQrYHOfG5HOqmVslRPCfyiRbIHH3JPD0lax5FudngdKy0+1nkkqVJCpRSf75cRRnxGPjdEvNzTEFmf5oGFxSVs7iXoVQvNXB35Qfyw5rV6N+JyERdu6a7xEnz9lbw41m/noKInlfP+uBQuaQIDAQAB"
- [Chrome Apps & Extensions Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc): "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDV/GMX7sjLe3ceUizalvfZK0qhsWnXcjJ3cCbYvXFo43Q2F7SZM8/0roex0wSpNRSO1j9c/m7YXLYBAOiy21ERRJEVEIvOvWp1LLeoBSsbQnnhSPKInqUrkA8fMRCqI0gHRUK3K7dIiOC2A7jkWUMs4DqRiQSkntUUGzVIoY6OYQIDAQAB"
- [Code Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cbelnpbjogfbjamhpbofhlnklecjpido): "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDIhi5zNAGD4SvQyCSVCj7KIt4w3OX0r9S7VFdxtzhagQVm58Kuz5XoJsbIhISEHjukldlZQZn9s0e9x1aK/s48ZJMe5KHyv6o0pYsslPEMro3aZG8bkPW9HMUMHe9uhyhw2DT90UMzWrOatOdj2QI41J+9Q4eP2TgXBTfJstE5QQIDAQAB"

Comment: This is good! However, is there any way I can safely charge users for this? I mean, if I charge them 99 cents to buy this IDE I want to make, and they get a CRX...they could just distribute it themselves for free. :/

Comment: They can redistribute it even if you don't give them the CRX, Chrome apps and extensions have no source protection.

Comment: Well, they can be protected if they're on the webstore and cost money. The CRX source viewer extension I have can't view the source of paid apps/extensions. But I can't even get it on the webstore anyways now. :( Boo.

Comment: If an extension is installed, you can copy it and debug it to get rid of any and all copy-protection if it does not include a significant server-side component.