# Opening background page of chrome extension not working

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome-extension, background, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to make my chrome extension open the devtools for the background page of my extension. That's what I need. Chrome does this when the user opens it using `chrome.developerPrivate.openDevTools`. However, when I run `chrome.developerPrivate.openDevTools()` in `background.js` I get an error. This is because it is priveleged API, is there any other method?

Edit: Can this be done through: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/devtools/ which talks about using:

`chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow`

?

Comment: Extensions can't use private API, those are for Chrome's own pages.

Comment: See also [How to load/build Chrome App/Extension and run programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35951201)

Comment: Okay, I edited my question to include that this is private API

Comment: Sounds like you want to open devtools for the background page, not the background page itself. Extensions can't open devtools programmatically. You can write an external program to send a hotkey that opens devtools to the browser window and run this program via nativeMessaging API.